# Using binary outcome variables in real-world data studies must be wrong?

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, propensity-scores, adjustment

Please be gentle if it's a stupid(ly easy) question:

In medical literature lot's of randomised clinical trials use binary outcome variables, such as **90% reduction in Y**, or **Y<(a certain threshold)**. Aside from issues of power, I'm okay with this since all groups have the same starting point (baseline value).

These binary outcomes are often used in observational, real-world studies, where the **starting point for each comparison groups is clearly different**. 90% reduction is clearly different for a group starting at 100, than a groups starting at 10 (absolute reduction ten-fold different).

Intuitively, I struggle to believe that **"adjusting for the baseline value" or propensity scores** solve the problem in these observational studies. Since, as in the above extreme example, there is **no overlap in distribution of baseline values in these two groups**. How can you "hold the baseline value constant" as is claimed in regression adjustment?

Comment: There are some important issues here. It would be easier to address them if you could link to some examples of papers that trouble you in these ways. Certainly if there is "no overlap in distribution of baseline values" then propensity scores won't be useful, but that seems to be a different matter from the binary-outcome issues you discuss in the prior paragraphs.

Comment: Many thanks. It's easy to find medical PS papers that proceed with very poor overlap (although no one would publish if *no* overlap) here is one example https://ard.bmj.com/content/early/2018/11/13/annrheumdis-2018-214652 ironically *teaching* how to use PS. Under what circumstances (eg overlap) is "adjusting for baseline" (either by PS/regression) *NOT* going to address baseline differences, eg when using fixed-%-reduction outcome?

Comment: The outcome variable in the primary paper that your link leads back to is the DAS-28, a continuous measure of arthritis severity that covers a range from 0 to 9.4. The comparison among groups was based on the rate of change of DAS over time regardless of the the initial value, so it wasn't a percentage change. Could you suggest an example with a thresholded binary outcome? On this site we try to provide a resource for others with similar questions, so that type of example might be more compelling for future visitors to this page.

Comment: Dermatology studies have 50%, 70% or 90% reduction ("PASI50" etc) and rheumatology ACR20 (20% reduction in some out of a collection of scores). These are mostly used in trials. The latter was specifically said NOT to be use in observational studies for the reason @sarapowell gave. Here is a potential example of 50% reduction https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26628579  although it's not comparing treatments and did not use propensity scores. Many many more studies use "remission" outcomes, ie, below a low threshold.

Comment: There is even a word for this "dichotomania" and it has all sorts of problems, the ones you mention are far from the only ones, e.g. https://www.methodsappraisal.com/education-dichotomania/

Comment: Thanks all. Yes, totally agree that it's problematic in many ways. I tried a "simulation" by fixing the absolute reduction (eg 20 reduction in a scale of 0-100) and see how different baseline values between the two groups need to be before analyses of 50%-reduction-binary-outcome no longer reflects the fact that there was *NO* difference. Alas, I am but an amateur, and something or other about perfect prediction doesn't allow me to run the simulation. I suspect I need to add some jitter to the 20-unit reduction...

Comment: @bobmcpop that suggested binary outcome is still a composite. Here is an example using just 50% reduction https://ard.bmj.com/content/77/4/533.long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem doesn't seem to be with binary outcomes or with propensity score analysis but rather with "percentage change from baseline" as the outcome.

Note that "raw change from baseline" is not problematic. If two groups are equated (i.e., with propensity scores or regression) to have the same average baseline, then the difference in change scores is equal to the difference in raw outcomes. If it's impossible to equate the two groups without extrapolation because of a lack of overlap, then confounding becomes an issue, but that is a problem in all observational studies and not just ones that use raw change as an outcome. If your problem is that for those with low baselines, there is little room to decrease, then you are describing a nonlinearity or floor effect that needs to be modeled, which can easily be done using a generalized linear model or a flexible linear model. For example, a model that contained an asymptote at 0 (like a fractional logistic regression) would reflect the fact that there is little decrease possible for someone already at a very low level of the outcome at baseline.

Percentage change can be problematic, as you have described. Two groups with the same raw change may have different percentage change if they start at different baselines, and adjusting for this by balancing on average baselines will not solve that problem. Even if the two groups had the same average baseline and the treatment was totally ineffective, you might see different percentage changes just based on the fact that those in the tails of the baseline distribution have different potentials for change. However, if you could *exactly* balance the entire distribution of the baseline, then the difference in the percentage change would be valid and  not confounded by the baseline. This goes way farther than most propensity score analyses go, though, but it is possible. For example, finding exact matches on the baseline measure would ensure that the distributions of the baseline in both groups were exactly balanced, so a simple difference in either the percentage change or absolute change would not be affected by confounding due to differing baseline levels.

Comment: Thank you and apologies for phrasing the question poorly. I understand there would be no bias through *exact matching* - this is really helpful in conceptualizing why PS would not fully work (since it matches overall distributions of two groups rather than individuals in each group?). My take-home is that the poorer the match/overlap, the more confounding by the baseline. So my rephrased question "how different do baselines need to be before false positive is found?" depends on too many other things (effect size, sample size) to have a straighforward answer... right?